# command line pdf print with soffice

Tags: pdf, openoffice.org, xls

I'm trying to print `xls` file to `pdf` using `soffice` on windows machine. i made "Adobe PDF" my default printer and i tried those commands:

```
soffice -p file.xls
soffice -pt 'Adobe PDF' file.xls
```

but i see no pdf outputted. Actually, something flashes in the print que but i cant read so fast.

Printer is configured not to ask where to save output file and it performs printing when i try it manualy. So, how can i solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone is interested look [here](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=63294&highlight=odoc%20print%20aprintops): all you need is to

```
Tools>Options...>OpenOffice.org Calc>Printing and uncheck "Print only selected tables"
```